# Receiving `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')` error with Material UI In Preact

Tags: material-ui, vite, server-side-rendering, preact, astrojs

I have an Astro project that I'm using preact and Typescript with. When I'm trying to use a MaterialUI `Typography` component inside of the project I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')
    at exports.useContext
    at useTheme (/node_modules/@mui/system/useThemeWithoutDefault.js:15:30)
    at useTheme (/node_modules/@mui/system/useTheme.js:13:46)
    at Box (/node_modules/@mui/system/createBox.js:30:41)
    at Object.t (/node_modules/preact/compat/dist/compat.js:1:1040)
    at file:///node_modules/preact-render-to-string/dist/index.mjs:1:6332
    at F (file:///node_modules/preact-render-to-string/dist/index.mjs:1:6359)
    at F (file:///node_modules/preact-render-to-string/dist/index.mjs:1:6434)
    at Proxy.S (file:///node_modules/preact-render-to-string/dist/index.mjs:1:4833)
    at Object.renderToStaticMarkup (/node_modules/@astrojs/preact/dist/server.js:55:45)
    at renderFrameworkComponent (/node_modules/astro/dist/runtime/server/render/component.js:187:66)
```

I already have `preact({ compat: true })` set in my integrations and I have react and react-dom actually double overridden in my package.json like so:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/preact": "^2.2.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
    "@preact/compat": "^17.1.2",
    "astro": "^2.4.1",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "preact": "^10.15.0",
    "preact-fluid": "^0.9.1",
    "react": "npm:@preact/compat@latest",
    "react-dom": "npm:@preact/compat@latest"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react": "npm:@preact/compat@latest",
    "react-dom": "npm:@preact/compat@latest"
  },
```

When I enable `client:only="preact"` on the component it works fine but I really don't want to have to enable that any time that I want to use a MaterialUI component.

I've looked at MaterialUI's preact sample repo as well and was not able to gleam anything helpful from that, did I miss something?

I have done a lot of googling on this issue and there seem to be a few different threads that are similar to this issue but not quite it, the closest one I could find was one talking about vitetest: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/747

The above issue makes it sound like the main issue is that Material and Preact/Hooks have a different import styles or something like that? I tried renaming `preact/hooks` package.json so it was ignored(I guess that's what's happening?) and then taking off the `--format cjs` from the `dev` command in that package as well and that didn't help at

Does anyone have any insight into how we can make these packages work together or is there just a hard incompatibility issue until MUIv6 comes out? I'm still not 100% sure what the issue is here, since Material and Preact should work together given that there's a sample repo for it. Is this a Vite/Material/Preact compatibility issue?

Comment: Just want to say that editing `package.json` scripts for installed modules will never do anything. Those scripts are there for developing/building/installing that module, they're never ran after that.

Comment: @rschristian Yeah I noticed that. Just documenting something I tried out of desperation while in the google hole.

Comment: any solutions for the above issue?? I'm facing the same as well with apollo client